# Python line remover

Tags: python

Hi I have a large file that I want to delete the lines that contain the text ALL and print the file without spaces with just the remaining lines. I started a program

```
sourcefile = open('C:\\scoresfinal.txt', 'r')
filename2 = open('C:\\nohet.txt', 'w')

offending = ["HET"]

def fixup( filename ): 
    fin = open( filename ) 
    fout = open( filename2 , "w") 
    for line in fin.readlines(): 
        if True in [item in line for item in offending]:
            continue
        fout.write(line)
    fin.close() 
    fout.close() 

fixup(sourcefile)
```

but it doesn't work. any help?

here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python Make Small File/hetcut2.py", line 18, in <module>
    fixup(sourcefile)
  File "C:/Python Make Small File/hetcut2.py", line 9, in fixup
    fin = open( filename )
    TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

Comment: you can replace the expression `True in [item in line for item in offending]` with `any(item in line for item in offending)`. This performs the same logic but stops as soon as it finds a match. This would be important if `offending` had a significant amount of items in it.

Comment: If you install unxutils, this is just `grep -v ALL filename`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sourcefile = open('C:\\scoresfinal.txt', 'r')
```

defines `sourcefile` as a file object. So

```
fixup(sourcefile)
```

assigns `sourcefile` to be the value of the local variable `filename` in the `fixup` function.

Calling `open(filename)` thus tries to open an already-open file object, when `open` expected a string naming a file or filepath.

You could fix the code this way:

```
sourcefile = 'C:\\scoresfinal.txt'
filename2 = 'C:\\nohet.txt'

offending = ["HET"]

def fixup( filename ): 
    with open( filename ) as fin:
        with open( filename2 , "w") as fout:
            for line in fin: 
                if any(item in line for item in offending):
                    continue
                fout.write(line)
fixup(sourcefile)
```

The `with open(...) as f` statement is available in Python2.6 or better. 
In Python2.5 you can use the with statement if you put

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you are guaranteed to close the file handles with Python exits the `with`-block. (Notice the explicit calls to fin.close() and fout.close() were removed.)

Using `with` is not necessary to solve your immediate problem, but it is the future standard idiom in Python, so you might as well get used to it.

Comment: Thanks the program runs but it still doesn't remove the lines that contain HET. It actually just prints output of nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Robert: Sorry for the delay. I made a small change and tested the code. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning, you open a file and store the handle inside of `filename2`. Then within the function, you are trying to use that `filename2` as a – well – filename, when it is instead a handle to an already opened file.

If you want that to work, you have to set `filename2` to the actual filename:

```
filename2 = 'C:\\nohet.txt'
```

Also, you should consider moving the target pathname into the function parameters, so it doesn't depend on some global variable.

Oh, and the same applies to `sourcefile` which is a file handle as well but which your function tries to use as a filename as well.

#### edit:

Like this:

```
def fixup( source, target, badWords ):
    fin = open( source ) 
    fout = open( target , "w" )

    for line in fin:
        if any( ( word in line ) for word in badWords ):
            continue
        fout.write( line )

    fin.close() 
    fout.close() 

offending = ["HET"]
fixup( 'C:\\scoresfinal.txt', 'C:\\nohet.txt', offending )
```

Answer (score 0):

2) sourcefile and filename2 are files, not a string.

Comment: `filename` is a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered (you are "opening the files twice") but I thought I should point out that you could tidy the code somewhat:

```
def fixup( filename ): 
    with fin as open(filename), fout as open(filename2 , "w") 
        for line in fin:
            if not any(word in line for word in offending):
                fout.write(line)
```

Also, you should consider using better variable names. `fixup`, `filename`, `filename2` (ugh!) are not very illuminating.